# How to find the best path in a network?

Tags: r, algorithm, networking, routes, igraph

I have a network. My bus starts from 1 and destination is node 10. I want to follow a path where I can carry maximum number of passengers given the capacity of bus is 40. To be more clear, if I go from i to j to k then my problem is while I am at node j and take a decision of going from j to k, I have to take into account the number of passengers who want to go from i to k because I am coming from i. How do i do this in R?

Now consider if I add demand(passengers) from 3 to 8 (D[3,8]) as 20. This problem is no more a simple DP.

```
D=matrix(c(0,30,15,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,15,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,30,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,60,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,60,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),nrow=10,byrow=T)  

library(igraph)

g2 <- graph.adjacency(D, mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE)

plot(g2, edge.label = round(E(g2)$weight,2))
```

Comment: What does the weight on the edges represent?

Comment: number of passengers available.(Demand between nodes)

Comment: Your question is not at all clear to me. What is the exact problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Abhishek made some changes, are you clear now?

Comment: So is the objective to 'transport' maximum number of passengers while going from a given source node i to a given destination node k? This is including passengers who board and de-board between the two nodes?

Comment: Yes exactly. The future node that I am going to visit will have some passengers from my past visited node. How to take that into account, that's what I ask.